# WL.client.connect failing only in android environment in IBM MobileFirst v7.0

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, worklight-server, worklight-studio

I have a IBM Worklight application with Android and iOS environment

Connection to server(https) is failing for "android Wl.clent.connect" call is failing for android environment but in iOS its connecting and application is working.
Status 500 is getting from connect call failure 
Worklight version : 7.0 with 0435 fixpack

testing devices used : Android 5.1.6.0,7.1
Ios : ios 9, ios 11,ios 10

Comment: What does the message say? Also, what do you see in the server side logs? 0435 fixpack of which year? 2016 or 17?

Comment: 2016 fix pack,  Its failing from Load balancer not hitting application server

Comment: Is there a problem with the application context or details in the wlclient.properties, that there is no mapping for it in app server?

Comment: App is working fine in IOS . Wlapp is deployed for both ,  the request is not passing from load balancer to IHS

Comment: If the request from Android reaches the loadbalancer without issues, and fails thereafter , check if there is a problem at the loadbalancer. Specically, the load balancer logs, what does it say?